# Config nginx with docker

Tags: nginx

I have a docker environment with Nginx and php-fpm.

Here is my nginx conf.

```
server {
    sendfile  off;
    server_name project.dev;
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/project/web;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

I have added `project.dev` in my `/etc/hosts` file.

It works very well when I use `project.dev`.

But I would like replace `server_name project.dev;` with `server_name _;`, so every connection to the port 80 will go to my app and will work in dev.

But it does not work when I do it.

What is the config to make every connection to port 80 go to my project without using a server name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave off the `server_name` and use `default_server` on your listen:

```
server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    ...
}
```